# BayazitDecomposer inaccessible when upgrading from Farseer 3.3.1 to Farseer 3.5

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

I used the following code in Farseer 3.3.1 and it worked correctly, but in Farseer 3.5, I always get an error message in the following line:

```
list = BayazitDecomposer.ConvexPartition(textureVertices);
'FarseerPhysics.Common.Decomposition.BayazitDecomposer' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

What is wrong? Why is the code not working with Farseer 3.5? How can I use the decomposition tools in Farseer 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's simply that the author of the package has changed the class from `public` to `internal`. As far as I can see, that happened in [commit 101636](https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/101636).

This is a breaking change, so should *not* have been done in a minor version IMO - but perhaps the author isn't following semantic versioning. You should probably file a feature request for it to be made public again.

Alternatively, you could try to find an alternative approach you can use to achieve the same thing. I *suspect* this is what you want:

```
list = Triangulate.ConvexPartition(textureVertices, TriangulationAlgorithm.Bayazit);
```